# Postgres query SELECT when field is set

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have a table `topics`. And I have two queries which select different data, one for the table `votings` and one from the table `messages`. `topics` has a field `m_group` which is a foreign key for `messages`. This field can either be `NULL` or a group for entries in `messages` (`group` is a field in this table). If this field is set to a group, it should perform query 1 to select all messages or if it is not set it should perform query 2 to select all votings for this specific topic. I'm using Postgres and PHP on an Apache Webserver.

Now my question is what is the recommended way to go. I came up with two solutions (not sure if solution 2 is actually possible, haven't tried it yet).

---

**Solution 1**

First select the field `m_group`. Then determine if it is set via PHP and perform the associated query.

---

**Solution 2**

Use a `IF THEN ELSE` statement

Basically the query should then look something like this

```
IF t.m_group IS NULL 
THEN
    query2
ELSE
    query1
```

---

As already mentioned, I'm not sure if solution 2 is possible. What would be the best way to handle this? Solution 1 performs two queries, I think this is inefficient.

---

UPDATE

As mentioned above, it should perform the queries for a specific topic. You have the `id` of this topic. How can you specify this in solution 2? And does the `IF THEN ELSE` statement already know the alias `t` for topics, if that is specified in the queries?

Comment: Doesn't solution 2 also do two queries?  I prefer option 2, by the way.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't exactly know how this works. But since the server on which PHP runs is different from the database server in my case, it's better to send only one command to the database server I guess.

Comment: Please can You provide the queries 1 and 2 to see the structure of their result? Generally, `IF` must return the same type of result in both branches.

Comment: Have you looked into using a stored proc to handle this?  You would call the proc once, then internally it would decide which of two queries to run.

Comment: @RomanHocke the queries are a bit complicated, but they both have the same structure. They return 3 values per entry `id`, `title` and `SUM(subtable_id) AS votes`, which also means both of the the tables `votings` and `messages` have subtables to store additional data

Comment: Why not write a single query, and use CASE statements for each field to the different results?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you need to use two subqueries as sets of data, while you should use one of them as a source depending on what's in the m_group field.  Your second approach is good if you only select a few rows. However, if you need to grab a lot of data from the table, this way you will need to perform too many subqueries. I would rather first grab all the data you need from topics and then select what you need with both queries.
Pseudo SQL query will look like that:

```
with t1 as (select t.id, group_m, ... from topics t where t.m_group is not null),
t2 as (select t.id, ... from topics t where t.m_group is null)
select id, title, SUM(subtable_id) AS votes
from query1
join t1 on t1.id = query1.id and...
union
select id, title, SUM(subtable_id) AS votes
from query2
join t2 on t2.id = query2.id and...
```